# Understanding metrics being sent by jmeter to graphite

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, performance-testing, graphite

I have started using jmeter 2.13 which has the support of pushing data to graphite. As per the documentation :

..a.count   Number of responses for sampler name

..a.min Min response time for responses of sampler name

..a.max Max response time for responses of sampler name

1. Is the a.count per second? or what?.
   In my graphite reports, I see them hovering around a particular value. Surely it is not for the load run till now.
2. The min/max : What time duration are they for?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace the tcp dump (`host graphiteHostNameorIPaddress and port 2003`) and see that each second backendListener sends the stats to the graphite.

`samplerName.a.count` is the number of executions for given sampler name during that second, `min` and `max` are also for that second.